# Flexbox - Repeat layout depending on items shown

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am trying to create a masonry style layout using flexbox, I am aiming for something that looks like this..

[image]

I can create the layout simply enough, but I would like the layout to repeat depending on the number of items shown.

Anyone have an example of something similar or any guidance on how to tackle it?

I was thinking of doing some PHP handling first to work out how many items there are and then generating the layout, not sure if this is the best way to achieve it though.

Comment: I do not remember where, but I definitely saw a video of someone doing a layout like this with flexbox. If I remember corretly, the key to this is setting the wrapper to have `flex-direction: row`, and enabling flex-wrap. Then each item should specify some `self` properties. I will look for the example for a few minutes, but I don't think I'll be able to retrieve it...   Alternatively you could use CSS Grid, if the layout is always 2 images / 3 images / 2 images / 3 images it should be fairly easy to implement. I personally always default to flexbox, and if it gets tricky I get the Grid out :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with `Flexbox` you just need to use `flex-wrap: wrap` and set width of first two items of 5 to `50%` and other 3 to `33.33%`. Also you need to include margin in items width.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.layout {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.item {
  height: 100px;
  margin: 5px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.item:nth-child(5n + 1),
.item:nth-child(5n + 2) {
  height: 150px;
  background: blue;
  flex: 0 0 calc(50% - 10px);
}
.item:nth-child(5n + 3),
.item:nth-child(5n + 4),
.item:nth-child(5n + 5) {
  background: blue;
  flex: 0 0 calc(33.33% - 10px);
}
```

```html
<div class="layout">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

You can also do this with Grid-Layout by using `grid-template-columns: repeat(6, 1fr)` and then making first two items `span 3` and other 3 `span 2`. This means that the first 2 items will each take 3fr units of 6 and other 3 will take 2fr units of 6.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.layout {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(6, 1fr);
  grid-auto-rows: 150px 100px;
}
.item {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.item:nth-child(5n + 1),
.item:nth-child(5n + 2) {
  grid-column: span 3;
}
.item:nth-child(5n + 3),
.item:nth-child(5n + 4),
.item:nth-child(5n + 5) {
  grid-column: span 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="layout">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I was just about to post the same thing. nth-child is perfect here but can be tricky to get your head around. Have a look at https://css-tricks.com/examples/nth-child-tester/ to work out what you can.

CSS Grid would be really great in this situation as well

Comment: Great solution, thanks for posting.  going to have a read through the nth child stuff now to make sure I fully understand it

Comment: @Adam Hughes I added css grid solution.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, that can be achievable by `flexbox`. Here is how you can achieve that:

```css
.masonry {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    width: 100%;
}

.masonry-item {
    overflow: hidden;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin: 0 0 8px 8px;
    background-color: #333;
    flex: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="masonry">
  <div class="masonry-item">
  <!-- this will be your inner content you dont need to specifically give this width and height -->
    <div style="width: 200px; height: 100px;"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="masonry-item">
    <div style="width: 150px; height: 100px;"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="masonry-item">
    <div style="width: 150px; height: 150px;"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="masonry-item">
    <div style="width: 250px; height: 150px;"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="masonry-item">
    <div style="width: 100px; height: 100px;"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="masonry-item">
    <div style="width: 100px; height: 100px;"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="masonry-item">
    <div style="width: 100px; height: 100px;"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="masonry-item">
    <div style="width: 300px; height: 100px;"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="masonry-item">
    <div style="width: 100px; height: 100px;"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="masonry-item">
    <div style="width: 150px; height: 100px;"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="masonry-item">
    <div style="width: 150px; height: 100px;"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="masonry-item">
    <div style="width: 100px; height: 100px;"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

No matter how much content you have this will fit them in masonry.